# How do I pass a variable to a javascript file <script src="../js/myfilename.js"></script>

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

How do I pass a variable to a javascript file?

Here is the call to my js file that I have on my page:

```
<script src="../js/myfilename.js"></script>
```

Here is the value that I want to pass into the javascript file:

```
language_value_xxx = "uk";
```

Here is the trimmed down javascript file (myfilename.js):

```
(function (language_value_xxx) {
....
language: language_value_xxx,
....
```

Comment: Read about the "module pattern", "Common modules" and "RequireJS". Or just share those variables in the global scope under a unique namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.

```
<script> language_value_xxx = "uk"; </script>
<script src="../js/myfilename.js"></script>
```

2.

```
<script data-lang='uk' src="../js/myfilename.js"></script>

// filename.js
var lang = []
    .slice
    .call(document.querySelectorAll('script'))
    .pop()
    .dataset
    .lang
    ;
```

Anyway, this methods are not a good practice at all )

Comment: Thanks, although this may not be the best approach, it will have to do untill I find a better way. Cheers.