# How do I pass a variable to a script as it's being loaded?

Tags: javascript

I'm adding a script to my page:

```
<script src="https://example.com/script.js"/>
```

But I would like to be able to pass a "key" to this script as it's being loaded, the key needs to be accessible by the loaded script, as it depends on it.

How can I do this?

Ideally something like this would be great:

```
<script src="https://example.com/script.js?key=authkey"/>
```

But I can't find much on getting this to work.

So far I've been adding an extra meta tag:

```
<meta
  name="key"
  content={"authkey"}
/>
```

And accessing it from the script:

```
const key = document.getElementsByName("key")[0].content;
```

But this isn't great. I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556837/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-to-a-javascript-file-script-src-js-myfilename-js) but it's not much better.

Comment: _But I can't find much on getting this to work..._ What issues are you facing? Where is the corresponding code?

Comment: Does this help? [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

Comment: The issue is that there's no way that I've found to actually access the query string from within the script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters to JavaScript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190801/passing-parameters-to-javascript-files)

Comment: `new URL(document.currentScript.src).searchParams` could work.

Comment: `document.currentScript` is `null` for me. I will try the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new Element `script` pass its src as your shown link and append in body

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  const script = document.createElement("script")
  script.src = "https://example.com/script.js"
  document.body.appendChild(script)
  
  const meta = document.createElement("meta")
  meta.name = "key"
  meta.content = "authkey"
  
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta)
  
  const key = document.getElementsByTagName("meta")[0]
  console.log(key.name)
})
```

**Edited:** I couldn't add `key` property as  attribute if I wouldn't use `setAttribute("key", "key")`, I used that method but appeared another problem

when I was grabbing that meta tag from `document.head`, it was showing that added Element, I also could print its `content` but not key, maybe because `meta` tag's default attribute isn't key, attributes that you can pass there are only **charset, content, http-equiv and name**, when I was printing `key.name` it was returning **"undefined"**, and then I changed `key` to `name` and worked perfectly, if attribute **name** doesn't cause problem for you everything works well

Comment: I added that soluion too